# Angular : make OnChange event async

Tags: angular, async-await, onchange

Angular is totally new to me. So in my application there is one onChange event of PrimeNG dropdown. And I want to make it async. Code is given below.

.ts file code :

```
onChange(event: any) {
    const month = new Date(this.date1).getMonth().toString();
    const year = new Date(this.date1).getFullYear().toString();
    
    let financialYear = this.selectedYear;

    let dt = this.service.getDashboardData(month + year, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(financialYear) as any));

    let data = this.service.currentUser;
    
    this.chartData1 = data.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear ? data.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear : [];
    this.loadChart(this.chartData1);
  }
```

service.ts file code :

```
getDashboardData(date: string, date1: string) {
    this.getDashboardResponse(date, date1).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        let data = res;
        this.currentUser.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear = null;
        this.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear = data.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear ? data.monthlyLeadsCountOfYear : [];
        this.loggedUser = data;
        return this.loggedUser;
      },
      error: (res) => {

      }
    });
  }

  getDashboardResponse(date: string, date1: string) {
    let data = this.api.http.get<any>(`${this.api.baseUrl}auth/getDashboardData/` + date + `/` + date1);
    return data;
  }
```

How to make it async? As it is not loading correct data. With this code, it is loading older click data not the current click data. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I guess you should look at https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable, to understand how observable works.
HttpClient requests returns observables.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the event coming from?

If the `change` comes from an `@Output` of a child component you're using, you can get the instance of this component with `@ViewChild`, and then get access to its `EventEmitter` `@Output` that is a subclass of `BehaviorSubject`, which is an `Observable` you can use in an async way.

```
@ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent: ChildComponent;
```

And then:

```
this.childComponent.change.pipe(...).subscribe(...)
```